# How does JSON determine a success from an error?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to JSON and have been using it with MVC3 ASP.NET but could somebody shed some light on how to return an error per a JSON result?

I have the following call from my View:

```
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "json",
     url: "EditJSON",
     data: { FilmID: InputFilmID, Title: InputTitle, Description: InputDescription},
     success: function (result) {
        alert(result.Message + " updating film " + result.Title);
        window.location = "../All";
     },
     error: function (error) {
        alert('error');
     }
  });
```

Controller handles the request as a success.  What would I pass back for a JSON error so that the error: function handled back at the View?

```
    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public JsonResult EditJSON(BobsMoviesMVC2.Models.Film film)
    {
       filmRepository.Update(film);
       return Json(new {Message = "Success", Title = film.Title });

       // What would I return for an error here?
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

jQuery uses the HTTP response code to determine success or failure.

HTTP response codes >= 400 are considered errors. HTTP response codes >= 200 and < 400 are considered successes.

Return appropriate HTTP codes from your server-side code to get the behavior you're after.

Comment: So, I would have to just add, Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest; before returning my json result?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know ASP.NET so I can't be certain what to do there. What you suggested looks plausible to me, though.

Answer (score 6):

Confirmed, in .NET you can put:

`Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError`,

or whatever error status code you wish, right before your JSON return statement. (Thank you Mariah).

Check out the 'error' option of the [jquery ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to see what you can do with the resulting error on the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

A header with a status code other than 2xx or 3xx, probably a 5xx or 4xx error code.

Comment: Hi, is there anyway you can provide an example?

Comment: I think you do Response.Status = "401 Something Error".